# How to turn on or off mobile LED Flashlight in Adobe Air Android?

Tags: air, air-android

is there anyway to control mobile LED Flashlight in Adobe Air Android.

using adobe air 14 on flash CC

Comment: you have to write your own ANE ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flashlight ANE or create your own. Here is one that I found: https://github.com/sewonist/FlashLight

With that ANE, you'll be able to control the LED flashlight like so:

```
if( Flashlight.getInstance().isSupported )
{
Flashlight.getInstance().on(); // turn on
Flashlight.getInstance().off(); // turn off
var mode:Boolean = Flashlight.getInstance().mode; // get torch mode
}
```